# is there anything that might cause a planet to stop getting sunlight permanently, or to only have light infrequently? (on the whole planet or part)?

Tags: the-sun, rotation, earth-like-planet

(writing a story)

Is there anything that might cause all or part of a planet to stop getting sunlight, or to have a permanent/ridiculously long-lasting perpetual twilight?

nuclear winter? volcanic winter? a change in rotation or axis tilt, or some kind of permanent eclipse (that one seems especially unlikely)?  maybe a more 'squashed' orbital path, or a super-duper slow planetary rotation?

or what about a day/night cycle on the order of years?

Comment: If you are [worldbuilding.se]  you might look at [would-it-be-possible-for-a-planet-to-go-without-sunlight-for-three-months](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159046) or [what-would-a-large-and-habitable-constant-twilight-zone-on-a-rotating-planet-looklike](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25408/)  or all of the [eternal night](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=eternal+night) questions

Comment: In the question. Are you looking for a realistic way for a planet to have a slow rotation, (etc) or do you need the planet to *change* its rotation.  Do you want everything to be normal, and then one day, part of the planet stops getting sunlight?

Comment: WorldbuildingSE also has some Q&A about planetary rings' shadow

Comment: An orbiting dust cloud between your planet and its star might do it.  Something like Epsilon Aurigae perhaps?

Comment: The length of a day on Venus is longer than a Venutian year.

Comment: "part of a planet to stop getting sunlight" tidal locking or very slow rotation (like mentioned above), or a ***giant*** crater near one of the poles as long as the tilt of the rotational axis with respect to the  orbital axis isn't large.